# SSRS export to Excel causes a "remote server returned an error: (401)"

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have a 2012 SSRS scale out with 2 servers. When users run  a report the report comes back in a timely manner but if the user tries to export the report to Excel the "remote server returned an error: (401)" error message comes up.  I have run the report on my local report builder with the same results.  This error doesn't occur all the time.  There are instances when the report executes as intended but the majority of the time it ends with failure. One interesting side not is if we put the report as a subscription it will be successful every time.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mention the error doesn't occur all the time. Who does it occur for? 401 errors are usually cause by "Unauthorized access". This seems like a permissions or Credentials error on the server you are encountering the problem.

See similar below:

http://bidn.com/Blogs/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized